# How does Routing work in PHP laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have just started playing with `Laravel` framework and I have seen this :

```
  Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Can some one please explain what is this ? I mean over all I know what is get . but why do we put 'foo' and then the closure we put ? 
Also where am I really getting the information from ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we declare the Facade of the Route, think like a shortcut to use the Route class.

After that, we choose the method of the route, it could be:

```
Route::get($uri, $callback); //get
Route::post($uri, $callback); //post
Route::put($uri, $callback); //put
Route::patch($uri, $callback); //patch
Route::delete($uri, $callback); //delete
```

Now you choose the url of the page, for example:

If you digit in the browser:

`www.foobar.com/user/profile`

Laravel will search for the route with the `user/profile` parameter, like that:

```
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

You can pass variables too,

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

After that, you choose the callback method, in other words, what is gonna happen when the laravel enter in the route.

In your example, you have the function example, just returning a simple "hello world".

The best pratice here is to create a controller

```
php artisan make:controller FoobarController --resource
```

And referece to any method of your controller

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'FoobarController@index');
```

Now, when the laravel find the route, it's going to redirect to the index method of the Foobar controller, and there, you define your logic

```
public function index() {
    return view('welcome');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firsty, read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing), it's super easy, even for the begginers.

Step by step:

`get` is the `HTTP` method you use on this particular route. The other most often used is `POST`, but there are more of them.

`foo` is the route, in that case will be: `www.example.com\foo`. You can put any name as you want and need.

As a second parameter to a `Route` facade you put closure/name of the controller/view you want to handle endpoint, e.g.

```
Route::get('foo', 'SomeController@method'); 


Route::get('foo', function(){ 
    return view('some.view');
};
```

There are lot more options in routing and they are not difficult to understand, just have a look on documentation or some video tutorials.